Avoid re-rendering of a custom function
I am defining a custom function in Google Apps Script that calls an external API to return some value in the cell. It seems like that it keeps calling this function at certain intervals or on opening the spreadsheet again.
Example: =FETCH_DATA(A1)
function FETCH_DATA(input) {
  var url = "https://example.com/test-endpoint";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
     'method' : 'post',
     'payload': {
      input: input
    }
  }).getContentText();
  
  data = JSON.parse(response)["data"]

  return data;
}

Is there a work-around here that makes the request only once and refresh only if the user saves the cell explicitly again?
A lot of other people recommend creating a custom menu and then directly replacing the cell value instead of defining a Custom function which is not feasible for my use-case.

Can I ask you about the details of the user saves the cell explicitly again? About A lot of other people recommend creating a custom menu and then directly replacing the cell value instead of defining a Custom function which is not feasible for my use-case., for example, the OnEdit trigger is useful for your situation?

There is no way avoid the calculation of a formula when the spreadsheet-pro is opened.
If the use of a custom menu doesn't work for You look for other ways to execute the function, like using a trigger. This might require to change your solution.
